# When using Bundler and Rails 2.3.5 I get uninitialized constant SubdomainFu when migrating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I'm using bundler with rails 2.3.5 and I'm trying to make sure everything is working correctly but when I do a "rake db:migrate --trace" I get this

`** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant SubdomainFu
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in`load_missing_constant'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:92:in`const_missing'
/Users/node/Projects/Race-RX/config/initializers/subdomain_config.rb:1
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in`load'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in`load'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:622:in `load_application_initializers'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:621:in`each'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `load_application_initializers'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:176:in`process'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in`run'
/Users/node/Projects/Race-RX/config/environment.rb:9
/opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`require'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in`new_constants_in'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in`call'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in`each'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in`invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in`invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in`each'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in`invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in`invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in`invoke_task'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in`each'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in`standard_exception_handling'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in`run'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in`run'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/opt/local/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/opt/local/bin/rake:19`

I don't know what could be causing this. I did however but my

require "rubygems"
require "bundler"
Bundler.setup

in my enviroment.rb file but that doesn't see to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have run

```
bundle install
```

Then execute rake using bundle exec:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```